# How do I specify, in package.json, to use the version that was flat installed by yarn in node_modules?

Tags: angular, intellij-idea, npm

I am having the problem where we are using some piece of work in-house library that lists the dependencies like angular, material, rxjs and so forth internally, which we install --flat with yarn so we have them available in node_modules. The problem is that IntelliJ doesn't know to offer all the cool completions and nice angular related features (like ctrl+click jumping to template or style files) without the specific angular packages being added to package.json (or I don't know a better way to configure this).

I have tried adding the packages manually myself, but, because I used the "^" wildcard, upon doing an yarn update, I broke my env. I was hoping that npm has some other wildcard identifier that basically takes whatever version is in the node_modules, without specifying the exact version (I currently do this). The reason for this is that the in-house library we use keeps getting updated and, with it, underlying dependencies might get updated also.

Comment: Please try marking `node_modules/@angular/core` folder as *Not excluded* in **Project** navigator - select the folder, right click > **Mark directory as | Not excluded** - does it help?

Comment: it's for Angular recognition in IDEA, not about wildcards